# How come people other than Ryuko can wear Senketsu?

Tags: kill-la-kill

If Senketsu was modified to only communicate and be worn by Ryuko, how come in a later episode, Satsuki can hear him? When Senketsu is rambling or something, Satsuki acknowledges him and confirms she can hear him.

Comment: Spoiler ahead! Maybe it's because they are siblings? It's worth noting that Senketsu takes much more blood from Satsuki than from Ryuko